# Solving $\iint_A \sqrt{|y-x^2|} \,dx\,dy$ where $A=[-1,1]\times[0,2]$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Solve $\iint_A \sqrt{|y-x^2|} \,dx\,dy$ where $A=[-1,1]\times[0,2]$

First of all I tried to get rid of the absolute value by understanding where $y-x^2$ is positive and where it is not.

After that I tried to solve those integrals using the Fubini theorem.

I got two simple domains to work on, the first where $y-x^2\ge 0$ can be written as:

$-1\le x\le1$

$x^2\le y\le 1$

If I mark it as $A_1$, what I get is:

$I_1$=$\iint_{A_1} \sqrt{y-x^2} \,dx\,dy$=$\int_{-1}^{1}(\int_{x^2}^{1} \sqrt{y-x^2} dy)dx$=$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{3} dx$

But this is quite a challenging integral, using integration by parts I found that:

$\int_{}^{} \frac{2(1-x^2)^{3/2}}{3} dx$=$\int_{}^{} cos^{4}x dx$

But no special reduction formulas were taught to handle that expression, and only basic trig identities were used throughout the course which makes me think there is another way to solve this problem.

I tried to think about using substitution, but I am not sure how to approach the problem from that aspect.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now that I think about it $\int_{}^{} cos^{4}x dx$ is not too tricky, but still I would like to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: The definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^n x \mathrm dx$ could be computed by establishing recurrence relations.

Comment: Right, but still I would like to know if there is a simpler approach to this problem

Comment: @איתןלוי your integral should be $$I_1=\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^2 \sqrt{y-x^2} dy\, dx.$$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\iint_{A}\sqrt{|y-x^2|}\,dx\,dy\stackrel{sym}{=}2\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{|y-x^2|}\,dx\,dy\stackrel{x\mapsto\sqrt{z}}{=}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\left|\frac{y}{z}-1\right|}\,dz\,dy$$
Now we may split the $zy$-square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into two triangles, above and below the $z=y$ line.
$$\iint_{0\leq y\leq z\leq 1}\sqrt{\left|\frac{y}{z}-1\right|}\,dz\,dy=\iint_{0\leq y\leq z\leq 1}\sqrt{1-\frac{y}{z}}\,dz\,dy\stackrel{y\mapsto tz}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}z\sqrt{1-t}\,dz\,dt$$
and by Fubini's theorem this is just $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$. Similarly
$$\iint_{0\leq z\leq y\leq 1}\sqrt{\left|\frac{y}{z}-1\right|}\,dz\,dy=\iint_{0\leq z\leq y\leq 1}\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}-1}\,dz\,dy\stackrel{z\mapsto ty}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}y\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}}\,dy\,dt$$
and this is just $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$. It only remains to compute 
$$ \int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{y}{z}-1}\,dz\,dy = \int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{y-1}+y\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\,dy=\frac{2}{3}+2\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}u^3\arcsin\frac{1}{u}\,du $$
or
$$ 2\int_{\sin(\pi/4)}^{\sin(\pi/2)}\frac{\arcsin(v)}{v^5}\,dv=2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\theta\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^5\theta}\,d\theta $$
which is an easy job through integraton by parts. The final outcome is $\color{red}{\frac{5}{3}+\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using beta function is better! by $x^2=u$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^{\frac32}dx={\bf B}(\dfrac12,\dfrac52)=\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac12)\Gamma(\frac52)}{\Gamma(\frac62)}=\dfrac{3}{8}\pi$$

Comment: Perhaps it would! The only problem is that I am merely a calculus II student that barely knows what it means.

Comment: So, I think you would better evaluate $\int\cos^4x\ dx$. :)